# Android : Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am stuck for days now. I am using the PhotoShareDialogBuilder in facebook. I used the content provider something like this :

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider*****************"
                  android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
                  android:exported="true"/>
```

But, it gives me the error whenever the code gets executed. Someone please help me out. I don't want to use any other api like simple facebook etc.
The error i receive in the logcat is :
09-06 13:56:14.575: E/ActivityThread(4202): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider.

My code :

```
 boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
                        FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.PHOTOS);


                if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(image).build();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
                }  

private FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(Bitmap... photos) {
    return new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .addPhotos(image);
}
```

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that these logcat errors:

```
...
E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
...
```

appear only if you do not have the Facebook APK installed on your emulator. After you install the FB APP app like this:

```
Macintosh:platform-tools admin$ ./adb install ~/Downloads/Facebook-[Version Number].apk 
758 KB/s (40857788 bytes in 52.574s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Facebook-32.0.0.23.15.apk
Success
```

These type of errors should disappear.

Good luck !

Answer (score 5):

This can be caused by:

1. No internet connection
2. Make sure you've added the internet permission to the manifest
3. The [hashkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488560/1441326) is wrong for the app
4. Your app id is wrong

My guess would be point 2

you probably need to add this to you AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: And are you sure the other 3 point on the list are not causing it?

Comment: I have the same issue... Checked all 4 points multiple times... I'm trying to get the new Facebook Like Button to work...

Comment: If Facebook app not available in your device/emulator then this issue occur."Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider", Please install Facebook app from GooglePlay or download apk from facebook developer account for emulator. :)

Comment: The thing for me is facebook login (which is what I am implementing) works, but yet I get these errors in my Log

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I noted that the problem is linked to the Facebook app, isn't installed on emulator or device.