# Parse with Facebook login - Possibly since APK v42 or Graph API v2.4

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-login

**Note:** I have since edited this question's summary as I believe the focus must shift from Android APIs to Facebook itself.

Ever since my devices updated to Facebook v42, or since Facebook updated it's Graph API to v2.4 ([7th August](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions)), my app has failed to login. My Samsung S6 (API 22) failed initially, and 3 days later when my HTC (API 21) updated the Facebook app it too failed to login when it had been successful until then.

***Initial Steps Taken:***

- I have attempted to remove the app from the test user's facebook permissions and re-add it - in this case, it asks to allow permissions then fails.
- I have tested multiple test users and all fail.
- I've disabled the pre-installed Facebook app - this allows for a webview to be the method of login, but it still fails. Taken from top answer at [Facebook login fails on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278509/facebook-login-fails-on-some-devices).

***UPDATE 1:***

ParseException taken from comments: "User logged in as different Facebook user."

If I log in with **my** Facebook credentials, the app does not give an error. As I am not a registered test user, it should create a user in the Parse database and continue to the MainActivity. Instead, the LoginActivity remains and my data is not added to the database.

***UPDATE 2:***

My HTC running 5.0 just updated the Facebook app today and now the same error Toast is appearing ("Facebook login failed"). I disabled and uninstalled the app but the Toast still appears.

***UPDATE 3:***

I have updated the Parse SDK, and changed my dependencies to reflect the latest Facebook SDK (4.5.0). Same error still occurring.

***UPDATE 4:***

The app logs in successfully on any emulator that does not have a native Facebook app.

---

***ParseLoginFragment - where toast is implemented***

```
private LogInCallback facebookLoginCallbackV4 = new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (isActivityDestroyed()) {
                return;
            }

            if (user == null) {
                loadingFinish();
                if (e != null) {
                    showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_facebook_login_failed_toast);
                    debugLog(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_facebook_login_failed) +
                            e.toString());
                }
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
              // rest of code
```

***LogCat with Native Facebook App Disabled:***

```
    08-14 22:50:28.151  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
08-14 22:50:28.151  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath caller
08-14 22:50:28.191  30719-30739/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-14 22:50:28.191  30719-30739/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
08-14 22:50:28.191  30719-30739/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-32296-266222247: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
08-14 22:50:28.191  30719-30739/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-32296-266222247: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
08-14 22:50:28.191  30719-30739/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-14 22:50:28.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/InjectionManager﹕ InjectionManager
08-14 22:50:28.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/InjectionManager﹕ fillFeatureStoreMap com.guile.occ
08-14 22:50:28.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Constructor com.guile.occ, Feature store :{}
08-14 22:50:28.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ featureStore :{}
08-14 22:50:28.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:50:28.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.guile.occ time:88929116
08-14 22:50:28.221  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
08-14 22:50:28.221  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.guile.occ.LoginActivity isFragment :false
08-14 22:50:28.231  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
08-14 22:50:28.241  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
08-14 22:50:28.241  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
08-14 22:50:28.271  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity isFragment :false
08-14 22:50:28.271  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:50:28.281  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-14 22:50:28.281  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:50:28.281  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:50:28.291  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:50:28.311  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
08-14 22:50:28.331  30719-30754/com.guile.occ I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-14 22:50:28.331  30719-30754/com.guile.occ I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f7d8d6b20 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 2107568816
08-14 22:50:28.331  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
08-14 22:50:28.331  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-14 22:50:28.331  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
08-14 22:50:28.451  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@38cba1f0 time:88929356
08-14 22:50:28.451  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2e8ef184 time:88929358
08-14 22:50:29.061  30719-30739/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
08-14 22:50:37.661  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
08-14 22:50:37.731  30719-30855/com.guile.occ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
08-14 22:50:37.731  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.guile.occ time:88938639
08-14 22:50:37.771  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
08-14 22:50:37.771  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
08-14 22:50:37.771  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
08-14 22:50:37.771  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.facebook.FacebookActivity isFragment :false
08-14 22:50:37.771  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
08-14 22:50:37.771  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
08-14 22:50:37.801  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.google.android.webview version 44.0.2403.90 (code 240309050)
08-14 22:50:37.801  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath caller
08-14 22:50:37.801  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 0 ms (timestamps 8709-8709)
08-14 22:50:37.801  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
08-14 22:50:37.811  30719-30719/com.guile.occ V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {23858b22}
08-14 22:50:37.811  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
08-14 22:50:37.811  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
08-14 22:50:37.821  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
08-14 22:50:37.821  30719-30719/com.guile.occ W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-14 22:50:37.821  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
08-14 22:50:37.831  30719-30719/com.guile.occ W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
08-14 22:50:37.831  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-14 22:50:37.831  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-14 22:50:37.841  30719-30871/com.guile.occ W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
08-14 22:50:37.861  30719-30719/com.guile.occ W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-14 22:50:37.871  30719-30719/com.guile.occ W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
08-14 22:50:37.881  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
08-14 22:50:37.881  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
08-14 22:50:37.881  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:50:37.891  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:50:37.891  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:50:37.891  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:50:37.911  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:50:37.911  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
08-14 22:50:37.921  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:50:37.921  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:50:37.921  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:50:37.921  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
08-14 22:50:37.931  30719-30869/com.guile.occ W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
08-14 22:50:38.001  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
08-14 22:50:38.001  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
08-14 22:50:38.041  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:50:38.041  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:50:38.041  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:50:38.041  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [667x461]-format:1
08-14 22:50:38.061  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@188ff958 time:88938965
08-14 22:50:38.061  30719-30719/com.guile.occ V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{30111b2c token=android.os.BinderProxy@38cba1f0 {com.guile.occ/com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity}} show : true
08-14 22:50:40.631  30719-30719/com.guile.occ W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30719
08-14 22:50:41.221  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
08-14 22:50:44.081  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
08-14 22:50:44.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:50:44.211  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:50:44.231  30719-30719/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:50:44.241  30719-30754/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [667x461]-format:1
08-14 22:50:45.901  30719-30719/com.guile.occ W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30719
08-14 22:50:45.981  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
08-14 22:50:45.981  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
08-14 22:50:46.001  30719-30719/com.guile.occ E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
08-14 22:50:46.011  30719-30756/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-14 22:50:46.011  30719-30719/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@38cba1f0 time:88946918
08-14 22:50:52.751  30719-30853/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

***LogCat with Native Facebook App Enabled:***

```
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ E/Zygote﹕ v2
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10033
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G925F_5.1.1_0030
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
08-14 22:59:45.761  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-14 22:59:45.771  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
08-14 22:59:45.781  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
08-14 22:59:45.801  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
08-14 22:59:45.811  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath caller
08-14 22:59:45.871  13249-13285/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-14 22:59:45.871  13249-13285/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
08-14 22:59:45.871  13249-13285/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-33185-403364762: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
08-14 22:59:45.871  13249-13285/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-33185-403364762: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
08-14 22:59:45.871  13249-13285/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-14 22:59:45.881  13249-13285/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
08-14 22:59:45.891  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/InjectionManager﹕ InjectionManager
08-14 22:59:45.891  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/InjectionManager﹕ fillFeatureStoreMap com.guile.occ
08-14 22:59:45.901  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ Constructor com.guile.occ, Feature store :{}
08-14 22:59:45.901  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ featureStore :{}
08-14 22:59:45.911  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:59:45.911  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.guile.occ time:89486819
08-14 22:59:45.921  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
08-14 22:59:45.921  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.guile.occ.LoginActivity isFragment :false
08-14 22:59:45.941  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
08-14 22:59:45.961  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
08-14 22:59:45.961  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
08-14 22:59:45.991  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity isFragment :false
08-14 22:59:46.001  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:59:46.001  13249-13319/com.guile.occ D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-14 22:59:46.011  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:59:46.011  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:59:46.031  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:59:46.061  13249-13319/com.guile.occ D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
08-14 22:59:46.071  13249-13319/com.guile.occ I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-14 22:59:46.081  13249-13319/com.guile.occ I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f7d8d6d60 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 2107732656
08-14 22:59:46.081  13249-13319/com.guile.occ D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
08-14 22:59:46.081  13249-13319/com.guile.occ D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-14 22:59:46.081  13249-13319/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
08-14 22:59:46.191  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ce0ed1c time:89487096
08-14 22:59:46.191  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@38cba1f0 time:89487096
08-14 22:59:58.291  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
08-14 22:59:58.401  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.guile.occ time:89499300
08-14 22:59:58.461  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
08-14 22:59:58.461  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
08-14 22:59:58.461  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
08-14 22:59:58.471  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.facebook.FacebookActivity isFragment :false
08-14 22:59:58.481  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
08-14 22:59:58.491  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
08-14 22:59:58.491  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
08-14 22:59:58.501  13249-13249/com.guile.occ D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
08-14 22:59:58.501  13249-13319/com.guile.occ D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
08-14 22:59:58.541  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@5562ab1 time:89499446
08-14 22:59:58.541  13249-13249/com.guile.occ V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2d7dbc2b token=android.os.BinderProxy@ce0ed1c {com.guile.occ/com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity}} show : true
08-14 22:59:58.691  13249-13457/com.guile.occ I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-14 22:59:58.911  13249-13249/com.guile.occ I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ce0ed1c time:89499810
```

Comment: What are the contents of the ParseException? Try break-pointing it or printing .getLocalizedMessage() to log, .toString() will not always work.

Comment: The exception is "User logged in as different Facebook user." Hmmm.

Answer (score 7):

Each Android iteration comes with its own `WebView` implementation, for better or worse. 5.0+ Androids use the app-based implementation, which gets regular updates and so on, but also is different than the previous implementations.

Long story short, I believe this my be the problem. The `WebView` could be maintaining the session for your login or keeping the credentials in cookie storage for repeated use/confirmation. I can not offer a direct solution here as I am not that familiar with the new WebView's insides, but try force clearing the session and/or the cookie storage before each new login and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean each Android device or each Android API? I am running the app on 5.0 on a HTC with no problems but failing on 5.1.1 on a Samsung S6. Tried your suggestions but to no avail.

Comment: More like every manufacter-API set, but this is not a rule. I am sorry it did not help, but maybe at least I pointed you in the right direction. Check Android 5.1.1. docks, changelogs and so on, it must be there :) Also, do you have your fb account linked with the system? If so, try unlinking it from the Settings and running your app then :-)

Comment: You've provided some good information so I've upvoted anyway. My credentials are stored on the device but I made sure that the app wasn't trying to access it (by way of Single Sign On, or otherwise) by disabling the native Facebook app entirely. This meant that a WebView would pop up instead when logging in, but the same result would occur as before.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote :-) I understand, by I think you should still try unlinking the facebook account entirely, just to make sure the 5.1 WebView is not importing those anyway

Answer (score 5):

I can see this in your logcat

```
08-12 19:48:53.371  32227-32227/com.guile.occ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
08-12 19:48:53.371  32227-32227/com.guile.occ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.
```

Which means its unable to conenct internet check this [Android : Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698419/android-failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-wakizashi-provider-platf)

And try adding this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
```

Comment: Okay, the gist of the comments there is that if you do not have the Facebook APK installed then it will not work. The device I have comes with Facebook pre-installed. I've tried it with it both enabled and disabled. When disabled, I receive a webview login but it still fails (as mentioned above). Also, I added the permission but to no avail.

Comment: Just a side, I think my LogCat at that specific test gives those lines because there was an internet issue. They no longer appear when I try to run it now, so your answer may still be helpful to those with those lines.