# facebook login on android app with facebook sdk 4.0 is failing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am trying to incorporate Facebook login for one of my app..It is saying always login failure..I am using Facebook sdk 4.0 version and followed link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4 to configure Facebook login ..Once it was able to sign in, after I update read permissions it is always failing to login..I have uninstalled Facebook app and installed, even this doesnot help

What could be the reasons for this failure?

Comment: Generate facebook app ID. Try to login with account from which you have generated facebook app id.

Comment: Have already generated app In  FB developers site, and using the project ID in my app. Facebook app is able to login , but the same FB credentails are not working in my registered app.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. It is a problem since Facebook updated their latest APK to v42. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973652/parse-with-facebook-login-failure-since-facebook-update-version-42-0-0-14-114 is still unresolved despite a 150 bounty so I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: It s working very well on LG Nexus, problem only occurring in Samsung devices...